# Confidence band for the ROC curve

Tags: confidence-interval, roc

How would you construct a confidence band for the ROC curve?

I do not mean a confidence interval for the AUC or for other parameters that can be derived from the ROC curve, but a confidence band for the curve itself.

I came across [this paper from Macskassy, Provost & Rosset](https://archivefda.dlib.nyu.edu/bitstream/2451/27805/2/CPP-03-05.pdf), but it is relatively old paper (from 2005), and also [this paper by Kerekes](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.167.7019&rep=rep1&type=pdf) from 2008 (but it does not provide a methodology which was not considered by Macskassy et. al.

I was thinking about using bootstrap, but then the question is how to order the bootstraped curves to get the 2.5% and 97.5% percentiles. One possibility is to order the curves by their respective AUCs, or another one-dimentional parameter (e.g. Youden index).

Any idea will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

I would use bootstrap, as I have done in [Robin et al. 2011](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-12-77).

I would select a set of specificities, bootstrap the, and calculate the confidence interval of the specificities at each selected specificity, no ordering of the curves needed.